# Need to write a result set in the form of Map<String, List<String>> to excel sheet

Tags: java, excel

I have a class that runs SQL query and returns the resultset in Map> format. Now, I need to store this data in an excel. Can anyone help me write the logic to store the result set I received to an excel sheet?

Comment: Your question is too broad, and no one is going to paste a full code on how to bring data from Java into Excel.  See if you can narrow it down.

Comment: There are lots of blogs and answers written for the same, have you tried to search before posting here.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use apache poi, utilizing their API's you can write your data into an excel document. Can't really help you with the actual code though but the logic somehow would be to loop through your map and then use the apache poi api to write that data into an excel file... more info on apache poi here: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook

Let me know if that worked out for you. Thanks!